# How many floors does the dungeon have?

Tags: danmachi

AFAIK, adventurers only reached floor 59th. But that isnt the end of the dungeon. How many floors the dungeon is supposed to have?

Comment: That is unknown at this time. It has been hinted at that the Zeus familia has been lower but no information has been given how far down they have gotten.